# Runge-Kutta 4th order iteration for $\ddot{z} = -\frac{z}{|z|}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I defined a potential function as

$$
U(z) = |z|
$$

this encodes a pressure field (or kind of). Assuming I have a particle of mass $m = 1$ I got the following motion equation

$$
\ddot{z} = -\frac{z}{|z|}
$$

And I'm attempting solve this using Runge-Kutta. With such goal in mind I defined $y = \dot{z}$ And I got the following system

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{y} = - \frac{z}{|z|} \\
\dot{z} = y
\end{array}
\right. \Rightarrow \dot{\begin{pmatrix} z \\ y\end{pmatrix}} = f(z,y)
$$

My RK iteration would be set up as follows

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{\begin{pmatrix} k_{1,z} \\ k_{1,y}\end{pmatrix}} = \Delta t f(z_n,y_n) \\
\dot{\begin{pmatrix} k_{2,z} \\ k_{2,y}\end{pmatrix}} = \Delta t f(z_n+k_{1,z}/2,y_n+k_{1,y}/2) \\
\dot{\begin{pmatrix} k_{3,z} \\ k_{3,y}\end{pmatrix}} = \Delta t f(z_n+k_{2,z}/2,y_n+k_{2,y}/2) \\ 
\dot{\begin{pmatrix} k_{4,z} \\ k_{4,y}\end{pmatrix}} = \Delta t f(z_n+k_{3,z},y_n+k_{3,y})
\end{array}
\end{equation}
and then I'd update $z,y$ as

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
z_{n+1} = z_n + \frac{1}{6} \left( k_{1,z} + 2k_{2,z} + 2k_{3,z} + k_{4,z}\right) \\
y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{1}{6} \left( k_{1,y} + 2k_{2,y} + 2k_{3,y} + k_{4,y}\right) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Am I missing anything here? because when I run it my point initially goes down (like for 3 iterations) and then it goes up again (I'm expecting the point to go to $z = 0$, what am I missing? Initial condition  is $z_0 = 10$ and $\dot{z}_0 = 0$

(If the formulation isn't the problem it must be my coding).

Comment: What IC are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with IC?

Comment: IC = Initial Conditions

Comment: Initial condition is z0 = 10.

Comment: Done, hopefully it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

The RHS is the opposite of the sign function applied to $z$. Hence you have a uniformly decelerated motion which alternates between the positive and negative regions, periodically. The analytical solution is straightforward.

Comment: Could you please derive the analytical solution?

Comment: @user8469759 Come on, you can solve $\ddot z=-1$, can't you ?

Comment: $z = At^2 + Bt + C$?

Comment: @user8469759: yes, but find the coefficients by plugging the initial conditions. Then determine when $z$ comes back to $0$.

Comment: But anyway is there some potential function you could suggest that *locks* my particle to $0$?

Comment: I see the point anyway, you just solve it piecewise. Given my initial condition I can derive the first piece, once I get to $z = 0$ I solve the other one.

Comment: @user8469759:if you want a potential that locks the particle instantly, I am afraid you'll need infinity.

Comment: I don't need it *istantly*, but just converging to $0$, not sure what you mean with *infinity*.

Comment: @user8469759: infinite deceleration.

Comment: @user8469759: a well damped linear system does that.